# Is this set infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we say that $B = L_1 \cup L_2$, $L_1 \cap L_2 = \emptyset$,also $B, L_1,L_2$ are infinite and we are given that $A \subset L_1$ and $B \backslash A$ is infinite, does that say that $L_1 \backslash A$ is infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Take $A=L_1$.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Remember that $L_2$ is in $B-A$, and go from there.